# Need help with require while modifiying a gem (active_merchant)

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm trying to add a new gateway to the `active_merchant` gem and I'm having 'require' issues when I try to run it from source.

(I think my problem is not `active_merchant`-specific, but more of a general Ruby environment issue, so I dont think the specific gem in use has to do with it.)

This is what I've done:

1. Cloned the Git repo for AM, to my local directory "C:\Users\jb\Documents\Aptana Studio 3 Workspace\active_merchant"
2. Went about doing the changes in the "billing/gateways" directory (this is just background info..)
3. Copied the "Sample Usage" example on AM's Git repo to `C:\Users\jb\Documents\Aptana Studio 3 Workspace\simple_gw_test.rb`, which starts with:

   `require 'rubygems'

   require 'active_merchant'`
4. Ran "ruby simple_gw_test.rb" and got the error message:

   `` <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require': no such file to load --
   active_merchant (LoadError)
       from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in 'require'
       from simple_gw_test.rb:3:in '<main>' ``

This is understandable, since I don't have `active_merchant` gem installed

However, I want to *use* the downloaded source in the sample file, since I'm modifying the gateway source continually.

I tried
    `require '/Users/jb/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/active_merchant'`

And then got the same error:
`` <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in require': no such file to load --
/Users/jb/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/active_merchant (LoadError)
        from &lt;internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require&gt;:29:inrequire'
        from simple_gw_test.rb:2:in `<main>' ``;

Any Ruby Guru who can shed some light greatly appreaciated!

--jb

PS: I'm using MRI 1.9.2 on Windows 7 x64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I scratched my own itch: After a couple of hours of "Pickaxe book-ing" and googling, I got the code necessary to bootstap the gem without it being installed:

`require_relative 'active_merchant/lib/active_merchant'`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have read access to that file. Ruby has given me that error before when I didn't have correct permissions.